# How to rename elements inside a list of lists in the an efficient manner in R?

Tags: r

I currently have a large list with around 5000 elements. A reproducible example is like:

```
List.5000 <- replicate(5000, c(list(A='A',value.A=10),list(B='B',value.B=20)), simplify = F)
```

which has:

```
> List.5000
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
[1] "A"

[[1]]$value.A
[1] 10

[[1]]$B
[1] "B"

[[1]]$value.B
[1] 20


[[2]]
[[2]]$A
[1] "A"

[[2]]$value.A
[1] 10

[[2]]$B
[1] "B"

[[2]]$value.B
[1] 20
....
```

When I call `names(List.5000)` it returns `NULL`. But when I call `names(List.5000[[1]])`, it gives:

```
"A"       "value.A" "B"       "value.B"
```

I would like to change the name `"B"` to `"Z"`. Is there a way to do this without resorting to creating a new list, then looping and reconstructing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(i in seq_along(List.5000))
  names(List.5000[[i]])[names(List.5000[[i]]) == 'B'] <-  'Z'
```

Or, if you prefer `lapply`/`map`:

```
List.5000 <- lapply(List.5000, 
                    function(x) {names(x)[names(x) == 'B'] <-  'Z'; x})

library(purrr)
List.5000 <- map(List.5000, ~{names(.)[names(.) == 'B'] <-  'Z'; .})
```

If the names really are all the same you could just do

```
ind <- names(List.5000[[1]]) == 'B'
for(i in seq_along(List.5000))
  names(List.5000[[i]])[ind] <-  'Z'
```

The bracket syntax is a little faster:

```
x <- List.5000[[1]]
microbenchmark(
  sub = names(x) <- sub("^B$", "Z", names(x))
  , ifelse = names(x) <- ifelse(names(x) == 'B', 'Z', names(x))
  , stringi = names(x) <- str_replace(names(x), "^B$", "Z")
  , replace = names(x) <- replace(names(x), names(x) == 'B', 'Z')
  , bracket = names(x)[names(x) == 'B'] <-  'Z'
)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr        min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
# sub      22.041  31.2265  58.24097  46.9650  78.5075 373.637   100
# ifelse   13.309  22.4110  44.00665  30.2235  65.1395 113.693   100
# stringi 153.880 313.0400 346.41543 358.4795 383.4130 631.354   100
# replace   4.067   6.3205  13.09022   8.1760  11.9280  54.075   100
# bracket   3.246   4.5265  10.38177   5.9180   7.9925  55.278   100
```

Still a little unsatisfying, as none of these methods modify the list in place.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `purrr:map()` and `sub()`:

```
library(purrr)

map(List.5000, ~sub("^B$", "Z", names(.x)))
```

Or use `stringr::str_replace` to keep to `tidyverse` syntax:

```
library(stringr)

map(List.5000, ~str_replace(names(.x), "^B$", "Z"))
```

You don't even really need `purrr`, you can just use `lapply`, but I really find `purrr` to be clearer syntax:

```
lapply(List.5000, function(x) sub("^B$", "2", names(x)))
```

**Update**
Per Ryan's comment, if you actually want to change the list names themselves, but not the values, you can use this instead:

```
change_names <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- sub("^B$", "Z", names(x))
  x
}
map(List.5000, ~change_names(.x))

[[1]]
[[1]]$A
[1] "A"

[[1]]$value.A
[1] 10

[[1]]$Z
[1] "B"

[[1]]$value.B
[1] 20
...
```

Comment: May I ask what the `^` sign is for? Is it for nesting inwards? And `"2"` is my `"Z"` above? thanks!

Comment: The `^` is a regex indicator that means "beginning of string" - this prevents the `B` in `value.B` from being replaced.  And yes, sorry, my poor eyes saw `2` instead of `Z`.  Will update.

Comment: @andrew_reece The output of `map` does not have the same structure as `List.5000`; perhaps that's what OP is after, but I think it's important to point out. Or am I missing something? Check with  e.g. `str(List.5000)`.

Comment: @Ryan and Maurits Evers, true - I may have misunderstood OP's intent.  Added an additional option that just changes the list names.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `plyr::rename`

```
out <- lapply(List.5000, plyr::rename, c("B" =  "Z"))
```