# Renaming Several Columns in Data Frames Stored in a List Simultaneously

Tags: r

I have the following list, which contains several dataframes that all have the same column names:

```
my_list <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = c(1:3), B = c(4:6), C = c(7:9)), 
                df2 = data.frame(A = c(1:4), B = c(5:8), C = c(9:12)), 
                df3 = data.frame(A = c(1:5), B = c(6:10), C = c(11:15)))
```

Is there an efficient way to rename all of the column `A`s in each data frame in the list simultaneously using base R functions?

I was thinking that something like

```
names(lapply(my_list, `[[`, "A")) <- "new_name"
```

may work, but I think I'm off track - the `lapply` function returns an object that might not work for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663249/how-to-rename-elements-inside-a-list-of-lists-in-the-an-efficient-manner-in-r/

Comment: It's also worth asking the question: if all the data frames have the same columns, why not combine them into a single data frame?

Comment: @Gregor: the data frames need to remain separate, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more base options:

```
# rename first column name
lapply(my_list, function(x) setNames(x, replace(names(x), 1, "new_name_for_A")))

# rename column named "A"
lapply(my_list, function(x) setNames(x, replace(names(x), names(x) == "A", "new_name_for_A")))

# lowly for loop
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
  names(my_list[[i]])[names(my_list[[i]]) == "A"] = "new_name_for_A"
}
```

Comment: I'd probably just add another line to the `for` loop approach. You could probably do something clever with a named vector, e.g., `name_map = c("A" = "new_A", "B" = "new_B")`. Depends on the situation. Is it a dynamic number of columns that need renaming? Can you count on the column order being consistent? (This was re: a deleted comment about  multiple renames)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list` and rename the column named 'A' to 'new_name" with `rename_at`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(my_list, ~ .x %>% 
                   rename_at(vars("A"), ~ "new_name"))
```

---

Or with `base R` by making use of anonymous function call

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) {names(x)[names(x) == "A"] <- "new_name"; x})
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
new.names = c('New', 'B', 'C')
lapply(my_list, `names<-`, new.names)
```

For the added example in your edit, you would simply change this to

```
new.names = sub('B', 'New', names(my_list[[1]]))
```

Comment: Simple and perfect for OP's case where "all the data frames have the same column names".